# Processbuilder succeeds in Intelij but not in Eclipse

Tags: java, eclipse, openshift, processbuilder, intellij-13

Currently I am trying to boot an openshift cloud instance from a java application.
To get this working, I created a shellscript (openshiftBoot.sh) containing following commands :

```
<code>
echo "Booting $1" 
rhc create-app $1 jbossas
</code>
```

In my java code I use the following :

```
<code>


    try {
     ProcessBuilder pb = new ProcessBuilder("/bin/bash", 
                            "/Users/..../bootscripts/openshiftBoot.sh", "test");
                    final Process process = pb.start();
                    System.out.println(pb.environment());

                    BufferedReader br = new BufferedReader(new InputStreamReader(process.getInputStream()));
                    PrintWriter pw = new PrintWriter(process.getOutputStream());
                    String line;

                    while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                        System.out.println(line);
                        pw.flush();
                    }
                    System.out.println("Program terminated!");
                } catch(Exception e) {
                    e.printStackTrace();
                }

</code>
```

In eclipse, the code instantly "executes" and finishes without booting a new openshift instance.  It seems like he just skips the rhc command.

In Intelij, everything seems to work perfectly.

Does anyone of you guy's have an idea what I've done wrong in eclipse?

Thanks in advance!

Koen

Answer (score 0):

Why don't you try using the OpenShift Java Client (https://github.com/openshift/openshift-java-client) instead of executing a shell script?  This is the library that is used by the JBoss Tools in Eclipse and the JBoss Developer Studio.  You can read more about how to use the OpenShift Java Client here (http://openshift.github.io/openshift-java-client/)